# Got the "ERROR: Cannot decode data link type 239" message when turn on sniffer mode

Tags: tcpdump, centos, snort

I would like install snort 2.9.6 into Centos 7

the installation is ok and the result of the self-testing mode is correct but when I run this command to change Snort into sniffer or nids mode. I got this error message:

" ***ERROR: Cannot decode data link type 239***"

I try to recompile again with including the " --enable-non-ether-decoders " option as these steps:

```
./configure  --enable-non-ether-decoders --enable-sourcefire
make
make install
make clean
```

I still get that error

Comment: This thread from the Snort mailing list is covering this issue as well: http://sourceforge.net/p/snort/mailman/message/32738017/

Comment: @slm            I cannot access that link

Comment: Same thread from the seclist's site: http://seclists.org/snort/2014/q3/612

Answer (score 2):

Unless your Linux has done something with DLT_ values which nobody should ever ever ever ever ever do, 239 is:

```
/*
 * NetFilter LOG messages
 * (payload of netlink NFNL_SUBSYS_ULOG/NFULNL_MSG_PACKET packets)
 * 
 * Requested by Jakub Zawadzki <darkjames-ws@darkjames.pl>
 */
#define DLT_NFLOG               239
```

which is what you get when capturing on an nflog device.

If you specified an nflog device (device beginning with "nflog"), then snort 2.9.6 may not be able to handle that, and you'll need to capture on a regular network device.

If you *didn't* specify an nflog device, then either snort explicitly opened an nflog device (which it shouldn't do if it can't handle it!) or it used the default device (which shouldn't be an nflog device).

What happens if you run `tcpdump -D`?  If the first device it reports is an nflog device, either it (and snort) aren't running with sufficient privileges to open ordinary devices but can open nflog devices or there's some other issue putting the nflog device at the top.

Comment: It lists nflog to be the first available network interface. that's strange. How can I change my lan interface (enp2s0) to be the first instead of nflog?

Comment: So it lists nflog *and* enp2s0, with nflog being before enp2s0?

Comment: Yes.It's strange,right? So,I have to run with "-i enp2s0" option to make Snort work